# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources' Android resource linking failed

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Here is the error from Android Studio

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleDebug]

> Task :app:clean
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugManifest
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugSources
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues
> Task :app:generateDebugResources
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:processDebugManifest
> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light (aka ca.greatwebdesign.masterminddeluxe:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light) not found.
  error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light (aka ca.greatwebdesign.masterminddeluxe:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light) not found.
  error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar (aka ca.greatwebdesign.masterminddeluxe:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar) not found.
  error: failed linking references.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2m 1s
12 actionable tasks: 11 executed, 1 up-to-date

==========================================================
```

I know there are so many people reporting this error, I have tried all of them but none is working for me

under **Build.gradle**

```
ext {
    var = '28.0.3'
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        classpath 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
        classpath 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        //maven {
        //    url "https://maven.google.com"
        //}
    }
}
```

==========================================================

Under **Gradle.wrapper.properties**

```
#Sat Apr 27 17:09:14 EDT 2019
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

Comment: Are you sure 2nd & 3rd dependencies should be there and not in module build.gradle file? Why different dependencies of support libraries (26.0.0-alpha and 28.0.0)?